# Socket.io doesn't correctly attach to http server in express application

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm pretty new to NodeJS and trying to get Socket.IO running with an Express application. I've tried to stick to the docs and tutorials as close as possible, but in the end, `socket.io.js` cannot be found on client side.

The server is being started as follows:

```
var app = require('../app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() { debug('...') } );
```

Routing/serving pages:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Including socket.io:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(express);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

And in the HTML file, for clients:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript">
```

But when loading the page, this JS-file is never found. I suspect that including socket.io via that previously created http server is somehow wrong... Or am I missing something else?

**Update**

I just found out that the snipped that includes socket.io is executed before the server is started (first snippet). They're in different files and the server-start one (named `www.js`) is configured as "start" script in `package.json`, the other one (`websockets.js`) required indirectly by that.

If I put

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

at the end of `www.js`, everything works just fine. But is there a way to do it from `websockets.js`, which is loaded before, e.g. by a server start callback function?

Comment: check other online tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path, like this

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And connect to your server from client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
```

also check if `socket.io` module is available in your `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Yeah, the module is there and hard-coding the path doesn't work either. But I have some new finding and will update the question now.